# How to initiate node_save() on module install?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

If I wanted to create a node programmatically when a module is installed what hook should I use to initiate `node_save()`? I found guides on how to make the node I just can't seem to figure out how to initiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's your own module, use [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7.x):

> Perform setup tasks when the module is installed.

or [`hook_enable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7.x):

> Perform necessary actions after module is enabled.

If it's not your own module, use [`hook_modules_enabled()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7.x):

> Perform necessary actions after modules are enabled.
>
> This function differs from hook_enable() in that it gives all other modules a chance to perform actions when modules are enabled, whereas hook_enable() is only called on the module actually being enabled. See module_enable() for a detailed description of the order in which install and enable hooks are invoked.